# How do i fix this error that occurs whenever i try to deploy a qt quick 2 program on an android arm emulator?

Tags: android, qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtandroidextras

Whenever i try running a qt quick application called andTest on an android emulator, i always get the following error

I have used the same settings (namely the android manifest) with a Qt widgets application project and it successfully runs on the android emulator with no errors. From what i understand, it seems it's not packaging some of the dependencies in the android apk during the build process. I have tried some solutions such as creating a qml file that imports all the need dependencies but it does not work. How can i solve this problem ?

```
W EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xee2d3600, error=EGL_SUCCESS
D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdeb6efa0, tid 1763
D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe72bf250, tid 1768
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.506  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.506  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vertexCoord;
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vertexColor;
10-15 02:03:34.507  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: uniform highp mat4 matrix;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float opacity;
10-15 02:03:34.507  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: varying lowp vec4 color;
10-15 02:03:34.507  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp float _qt_order;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float _qt_zRange;
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position = matrix * vertexCoord;
W libandTest.so:     color = vertexColor * opacity;
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z * _qt_zRange + _qt_order) * gl_Position.w;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.539  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.539  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: varying lowp vec4 color;
10-15 02:03:34.543  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_FragColor = color;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): shader compilation failed:
W libandTest.so: ""
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.603  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.603  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: uniform highp mat4 matrix;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp vec2 textureScale;
10-15 02:03:34.605  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vCoord;
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec2 tCoord;
10-15 02:03:34.605  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: varying highp vec2 sampleCoord;
10-15 02:03:34.605  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp float _qt_order;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float _qt_zRange;
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:      sampleCoord = tCoord * textureScale;
W libandTest.so:      gl_Position = matrix * vCoord;
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z * _qt_zRange + _qt_order) * gl_Position.w;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.638  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.638  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: varying highp vec2 sampleCoord;
10-15 02:03:34.640  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump sampler2D _qt_texture;
W libandTest.so: uniform lowp vec4 color;
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump float alphaMin;
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump float alphaMax;
10-15 02:03:34.640  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_FragColor = color * smoothstep(alphaMin,
W libandTest.so:                                       alphaMax,
W libandTest.so:                                       texture2D(_qt_texture, sampleCoord).a);
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): shader compilation failed:
W libandTest.so: ""
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::link: (
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( alphaMin ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( alphaMax ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.771  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.771  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vertexCoord;
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vertexColor;
10-15 02:03:34.772  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: uniform highp mat4 matrix;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float opacity;
10-15 02:03:34.772  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: varying lowp vec4 color;
10-15 02:03:34.772  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp float _qt_order;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float _qt_zRange;
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position = matrix * vertexCoord;
W libandTest.so:     color = vertexColor * opacity;
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z * _qt_zRange + _qt_order) * gl_Position.w;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.794  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.794  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: varying lowp vec4 color;
10-15 02:03:34.795  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_FragColor = color;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): shader compilation failed:
W libandTest.so: ""
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.834  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.834  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: uniform highp mat4 matrix;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp vec2 textureScale;
10-15 02:03:34.836  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vCoord;
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec2 tCoord;
10-15 02:03:34.836  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: varying highp vec2 sampleCoord;
10-15 02:03:34.836  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp float _qt_order;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float _qt_zRange;
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:      sampleCoord = tCoord * textureScale;
W libandTest.so:      gl_Position = matrix * vCoord;
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z * _qt_zRange + _qt_order) * gl_Position.w;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.866  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.866  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: varying highp vec2 sampleCoord;
10-15 02:03:34.866  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump sampler2D _qt_texture;
W libandTest.so: uniform lowp vec4 color;
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump float alphaMin;
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump float alphaMax;
10-15 02:03:34.866  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_FragColor = color * smoothstep(alphaMin,
W libandTest.so:                                       alphaMax,
W libandTest.so:                                       texture2D(_qt_texture, sampleCoord).a);
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::link: (Ú²Ä
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): shader compilation failed:
W libandTest.so: "(Ú²\u000BÄ\u0089"
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( alphaMin ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( alphaMax ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:34.989  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:34.989  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vertexCoord;
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vertexColor;
10-15 02:03:34.990  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: uniform highp mat4 matrix;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float opacity;
10-15 02:03:34.990  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: varying lowp vec4 color;
10-15 02:03:34.990  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp float _qt_order;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float _qt_zRange;
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position = matrix * vertexCoord;
W libandTest.so:     color = vertexColor * opacity;
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z * _qt_zRange + _qt_order) * gl_Position.w;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:35.014  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:35.014  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: varying lowp vec4 color;
10-15 02:03:35.015  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_FragColor = color;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::link: ð¬h
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): shader compilation failed:
W libandTest.so: "ð\u0013¬h"
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:35.072  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:35.072  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: uniform highp mat4 matrix;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp vec2 textureScale;
10-15 02:03:35.073  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec4 vCoord;
W libandTest.so: attribute highp vec2 tCoord;
10-15 02:03:35.073  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: varying highp vec2 sampleCoord;
10-15 02:03:35.073  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: attribute highp float _qt_order;
W libandTest.so: uniform highp float _qt_zRange;
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:      sampleCoord = tCoord * textureScale;
W libandTest.so:      gl_Position = matrix * vCoord;
W libandTest.so:     gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z * _qt_zRange + _qt_order) * gl_Position.w;
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:2: error(#101) Macro redefined: lowp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:3: error(#101) Macro redefined: mediump
W libandTest.so: ERROR: 0:4: error(#101) Macro redefined: highp
W libandTest.so: ERROR: error(#273) 3 compilation errors.  No code generated
10-15 02:03:35.110  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
10-15 02:03:35.110  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): *** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): #define lowp
W libandTest.so: #define mediump
W libandTest.so: #define highp
W libandTest.so: #line 1
W libandTest.so: varying highp vec2 sampleCoord;
10-15 02:03:35.113  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump sampler2D _qt_texture;
W libandTest.so: uniform lowp vec4 color;
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump float alphaMin;
W libandTest.so: uniform mediump float alphaMax;
10-15 02:03:35.113  1743  1768 W libandTest.so:
W libandTest.so: void main()
W libandTest.so: {
W libandTest.so:     gl_FragColor = color * smoothstep(alphaMin,
W libandTest.so:                                       alphaMax,
W libandTest.so:                                       texture2D(_qt_texture, sampleCoord).a);
W libandTest.so: }
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): ***
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): shader compilation failed:
W libandTest.so: ""
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( alphaMin ): shader program is not linked
W libandTest.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( alphaMax ): shader program is not linked
```